# Glue for leather parts

Tags: adhesives, leather

I want to glue pieces of leather together, but I am looking for a glue that won't burn the leather or make it rigid.

The glue will be applied on the edges, for a few millimeters long(4-5mm).

Can anyone recommend a brand of glue which fits the described scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **specialist leather glues** available that are ideal for this application ([on Amazon, for example](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=leather%20glue&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aleather%20glue)), but if you don't want to buy glue just for one small join then ordinary **contact adhesive** will do a good job. **Epoxy resin** will also join the leather, but is less flexible.

Many people also swear by [Barge cement](http://www.bargeadhesive.com/products.html), but I've not used either so can't really comment as to their effectiveness.

Avoid superglue and PVA, which will both do a poor job of sticking the leather together and will make it brittle (superglue moreso than PVA).

However, bear in mind that gluing is normally not as strong as stitching or riveting; if you expect the join to be under any kind of tension I would recommend that you stitch or rivet it instead. (thanks to Matt for reminding me of this)

Sources: experience, [here](https://www.hunker.com/13414949/how-to-glue-leather-to-leather), [here](http://blog.leathercraftlibrary.com/2015/02/04/adhesives-what-to-use-when-and-why/) and [here](http://leatherworker.net/forum/topic/57007-best-glue-for-leather-on-leather/)

Comment: I have used contact adhesive with good results. Depending on the application though I would not rely on glue itself and would consider sewing as well.

Comment: Agreed; I prefer to stitch or rivet my leather projects too, but given the OP asked only about gluing I didn't think to mention it.

Comment: We do both. Glue first then stich second and it has worked perfectly

Comment: Yes, glue first then stitch, works perfectly! Then you can easily burnish edged

Answer (score 0):

The amount of stresses that the joined edges will be subject to, may determine your glue. Are you joining the leather end to end or like pages in a book?  Are you seeking whole cloth with one or two sides visible?  A fabric store will possibly carry your target product.

I suspect you are attempting to join two edges to make whole cloth and if you  expect only one side to be visible then there is a strong yet flexible option.  Take a piece of nylon cloth or other sturdy fabric and cut it to length with a measurable amount of overlap on both sides.  Join the edges snuggly then apply your glue to the overlap and compress the binding strip for the drying time and you should have whole cloth with the binding on the reverse not being visible.   The glue will seep into the crevice created by the joint and will serve to hold the edges. To much glue will seep beyond the crevice and contaminate the finish side, so be cautious.

Comment: I will join 2 edged like in a wallet. Just for the uniform look, they are already stitched.